# What is the definition of "since now" for FSEventStreamCreate

Tags: c, macos, fsevents

This might seem an odd question but I want to be certain I've understood this correctly.  In the [fsevents manual on FSEventStreamCreate()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1443980-fseventstreamcreate?language=objc):

> Creates a new FS event stream object with the given parameters. In order to start receiving callbacks you must also call FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop() and FSEventStreamStart().
>
> ...
>
> **sinceWhen:** The service will supply events that have happened after the
> given event ID. To ask for events "since now" pass the constant
> kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow. Often, clients will supply the
> highest-numbered FSEventStreamEventId they have received in a
> callback, which they can obtain via the
> FSEventStreamGetLatestEventId() accessor. Do not pass zero for
> sinceWhen, unless you want to receive events for every directory
> modified since "the beginning of time" -- an unlikely scenario. ...

**Does "since now" mean from the FSEventStreamCreate, or from the FSEventStreamStart call?**

---

At a high level, I want to register a stream **and then** kick off a process which will modify a file at really at sporadic intervals.  The monitor must not miss a modification between the the start of processing the file and the start of the stream or it could be minutes or hours before the next modification.

So I have two threads:

- call FSEventStreamCreate()
- start a separate thread which will:

  - call FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop()
  - call FSEventStreamStart()
  - call CFRunLoopRun()
- kick off file processing

Depending on interpretation, this threading model might be perfectly safe or have a race condition where the stream starts with FSEventStreamStart() call and occurs after file processing starts.